KVM/libvirt VMs layer 2 looks good but layer 3 isn't working
This looks like it's similar to this question but my setup (kvm/libvirt) looks closer to the answer than the question.
Host is running Debian 12 (bookworm) and is up-to-date with upgrades, nothing outside of the standard packages with the required libvirt-{clients,daemon,daemon-system,etc}/stable 9.0.0-4 amd64 installed.
Like the title says, I can see the mac addresses registered to the port (trunked) on the switch the host is connected to (along with the host mac address). The host is getting IP connectivity just fine. The guests have both dhcp and static IPs configured on different VLANs. I can provide tcpdump captures for any of the interfaces/protocols but it all looks like it should except for no layer 3 connectivity. Packet captures show mDNS and broadcast traffic from these VMs but that is all, nothing else.
Example Bridge:
$ brctl show br20

bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br20            ffff.4ab4a2a374f4       no              bond0
                                                        vnet2
                                                        vnet4
                                                        vnet5

And the interfaces:
$ip a                                                                                     
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br20 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ea:47:55:68:9d:21 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: br10: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ce:e4:a8:65:82:17 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::cce4:a8ff:fe65:8217/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: br20: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 4a:b4:a2:a3:74:f4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.20.19/23 metric 50 brd 10.0.21.255 scope global dynamic br20
       valid_lft 62120sec preferred_lft 62120sec
    inet6 fe80::48b4:a2ff:fea3:74f4/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: br30: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 6e:d1:73:de:65:b3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::6cd1:73ff:fede:65b3/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: br40: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f6:4a:b6:a4:f5:7a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fdb5:c811:ef42:2fc:f44a:b6ff:fea4:f57a/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 1348sec preferred_lft 1348sec
    inet6 fe80::f44a:b6ff:fea4:f57a/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: br50: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 92:47:00:08:04:d2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::9047:ff:fe08:4d2/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
8: local.50@bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br50 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ea:47:55:68:9d:21 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
9: security.40@bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br40 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ea:47:55:68:9d:21 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
10: guest.30@bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br30 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ea:47:55:68:9d:21 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
11: mgmt.10@bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br10 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ea:47:55:68:9d:21 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
12: br-27861bffb42c: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:a7:95:00:81 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.18.0.1/16 brd 172.18.255.255 scope global br-27861bffb42c
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
13: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:3d:97:16:1c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
14: vnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br40 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:9f:cc:34 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
15: vnet1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br50 state UKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:90:48:8e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
16: vnet2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br20 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:9f:66:4d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
17: vnet3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br40 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:02:9d:9d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
18: vnet4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br20 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:f7:dc:b8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
19: vnet5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br20 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:7b:16:db brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

This looks exactly the same as the other hosts I've setup before and the crazy thing is that it worked at first but stopped at some point after having it running for a day or so.
Kernel support for IP forwarding is enabled:
$cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1

From the router/dhcp server the arp table shows(for example a VM with an interface on VLAN 20):
hostname (10.0.20.xx) at <incomplete> on eth2.20

But my (cisco) switch shows the same interface's mac address in the address-table exactly as you would expect, as if it had a cable connected to it. I am at a complete loss as to why this isn't working, can someone point me in the right direction?

Can you: disable Docker (systemctl disable docker docker.socket) and reboot (yes the reboot is needed to avoid a much longer comment here). Does it work again?

You have multiple guest systems right? their virtual interfaces are vnetX and those do not obtain IP address from the switch which is br20, and your host's NIC is eno1 is that correct? which firewall do you use? iptables or nftables?

It was iptables. I really didn't think I had it installed. Just needed a second (or third) set of eyes.

@A.B docker wasn't to blame... this time :p.
